# What actually Power factor is, in practically?

Tags: voltage

What actually power factor is? I know its formula, but in practically i don't know, what happen if we increase or decrease the power factor? What is the use of power factor?

Answer (score 1):

The practical uses of the power factor vary, but its primary physical manifestation is the quotient of active current to total current flow in the conductor. There is actually more current flowing in the conductor if the power factor of an AC device is less than 1.

This is useful for instance for Joule loss calculations; if you know the power factor of a device is 0.5 and its active current draw is 1A, you know that you can model the losses in the conductor as 4 times the losses that would occur if the power factor were 1:

$$P_{loss} = I_{apparent}^2R = \left(\frac{I_{active}}{PF}\right)^2R$$

Another application is for the calculation of required wire gauge; if a device with a particularly low power factor is supposed to be connected to a wire, care must be taken to oversize the wire to accomodate the extra current that will flow.

Answer (score 0):

What they told me in physics class is that power factor is very important to utilities. The power loss in the transmission lines is determined by current, not delivered power. When the power factor is low, relatively high current is flowing, but customers only pay for the actual power. So if power factor is low, the utility is paying good money to burn fuel and heat up the transmission lines, and the customer is not paying the utility for it. So the utility puts limits on power factor.

Comment: customers are charged in VA. Home users in Wh

Comment: @JonRB, what is a customer as opposed to a home user? You mean industrial customers?

Comment: Not just industrial. As I recall in the UK if you request a 3phase feed to your home you are charged in VA

Comment: @JonRB, makes sense. My main point in my comment was that it seems to me that "home users" are customers of the utility, so I wanted to clarify what distinction you were making. I think I understand now. It makes sense that anyone requesting three-phase may be running inductive loads, so the utility might be justified in suspecting low power factor in that case.